# Parameter in collection() not working in xquery

Tags: xquery

Can anyone tell me why the first xquery returns the desired results, but the second one returns nothing?  To my eye, they are identical.

Query 1)

```
for $current-record-eids in collection( "EBOOK-AUTO" )
return $current-record-eids
```

Query 2)

```
let $collection as xs:string  := "EBOOK-AUTO"
for $current-record-eids in collection( "{$collection}" )  
return $current-record-eids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in function calls. Just pass the value like a normal parameter:

```
let $collection as xs:string  := "EBOOK-AUTO"
for $current-record-eids in collection($collection)  
return $current-record-eids
```

Comment: wst - Thanks! Worked like a charm.  I thought I had tried that, but realize now that I tried ( "$collection" ) whereas your solution doesn't have the double-quotes.